# Export Gridview with image to Excel - Problem

Tags: asp.net, image, export-to-excel

I have a Gridview in my ASP.NET C# Page.  It has a couple of columns and also one image column.  I can export the entire columns to an Excel file, but the image column is blank.  By the way, I use the full path.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes in default.aspx (For local Export)

```
ImageUrl="http://localhost:4056/CSharp/banner.gif"
instead of ImageUrl="~/banner.gif"
```

or (For remote Export)

```
http://your ip address here :port/foldername/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Response.Clear(); //this clears the Response of any headers or previous output
        Response.Buffer = true; //make sure that the entire output is rendered simultaneously

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); //System.IO namespace should be used

    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    GridView2.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    GridView2.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
```